# how to make horizontal tabs joomla 3.0 using jhtml::tabs

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

can someone help me to create horizontal tab in joomla 3.0 component i m using this code

```
$options = array(
    'onActive' => 'function(title, description){
        description.setStyle("display", "block");
        title.addClass("open").removeClass("closed");
    }',
    'onBackground' => 'function(title, description){
        description.setStyle("display", "none");
        title.addClass("closed").removeClass("open");
    }',
    'startOffset' => 0,  // 0 starts on the first tab, 1 starts the second, etc...
    'useCookie' => true, // this must not be a string. Don't use quotes.
);

echo JHtml::_('tabs.start', 'tab_group_id', $options);

echo JHtml::_('tabs.panel', JText::_('PANEL_1_TITLE'), 'panel_1_id');
echo 'Panel 1 content can go here.';

echo JHtml::_('tabs.panel', JText::_('PANEL_2_TITLE'), 'panel_2_id');
echo 'Panel 2 content can go here.';

echo JHtml::_('tabs.end');
```

it's output like:-

```
tab1
tab2
tab3
```

but i want output like :- tab1 tab2 tab3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$document =& JFactory::getDocument();
$style = 'dt.tabs h3 {
            float:left;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        div.current {
            clear: both;
        }';
$document->addStyleDeclaration( $style );
```

Just add in a style to the item. It will be along the lines of styling a css menu. Something like the above seems to work ok!

Comment: thanks @wilson it's working is there any way to make like Jpane. i m using it in 1.5 and 2.5 Jpane it's give horizontal tab without any css changes.

Comment: Not that I know of I'm afraid! But I haven't really explored it that far. I was just happy to use CSS styling.

Comment: ya thanks i m also using your css now but i m searching if any solution have

Comment: Rakesh what do you mean when you say make it like JPane?  You might take a look at the com_contact layout since it supports both tabs and sliders.

Answer (score 3):

This will make tabs as well open a set tab on page load

```
<!-- code to open default tab -->
<?php
$options = array(
    'active'    => 'tab1_id'    // Not in docs, but DOES work
);
?>
<!-- code end to open default tab -->

<?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.startTabSet', 'ID-Tabs-Group', $options);?> 

<?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.addTab', 'ID-Tabs-Group', 'tab1_id', JText::_('COM_BOOTSTRAPTABS_TAB_1')); ?> 
<p>Content of the first tab.</p> 
<?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTab');?> 

<?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.addTab', 'ID-Tabs-Group', 'tab2_id', JText::_('COM_BOOTSTRAPTABS_TAB_2')); ?> 
<p>Content of the second tab.</p> 
<?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTab');?> 

<?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTabSet');?>
```

Answer (score 0):

JPane was removed in 2.5, now use [JHtmlTabs](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_JHtmlTabs_class_in_a_component) it should do the trick ;)